# How do I get rid of the extra space in tables with Microsoft Word 2003?

Tags: microsoft-word-2003

I am copying and pasting tables from another document (Word 2007) over to Word 2003 and when I do this, right click on the upper left hand corner of the table, AutoFit, AutoFit to Contents, I am left with unknown spaces.  These spaces are ones that cannot be deleted.  They're like a paragraphing problem, but I don't know how to edit it.  Anyone have any ideas?

[image: Annotated screenshot]

Comment: Unfortunately none of the suggestions above worked for me. But one of my tables didn't have the space so I used format painter to copy the 'lack of space' to my other tables.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How to fix this: Select the table, then right-click -> Table Properties.  On the Row tab, disable "specify height" and you are golden.

Answer (score 5):

Highlight the table, select 'Line and Paragraph spacing' button and 'Remove space after paragraph'. Just worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the problem is that you can't access paragraph settings within tables.
I know a way around this (there may be others):

1. You copy the contents of one of the cells and paste in into the main
   body of the doc (outside of the table.)
2. Then you select the copied text, right-click on it and use the
   paragraph settings (not available from within the table) and set the
   paragraph spacing to zero.
3. Copy this "fixed" text back into the table.
4. Select the cell and use the "Format Painter" tool (Left corner of
   the home ribbon) to copy the corrected formatting to other cells

Works for me every time.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the horizontal space: highlight the table, go to Format menu, Choose Wrap Text and Choose Edit Wrap Points and then drag to modify (I'm not sure if you can do all the cells together, but as of now I can do it one by one). For the vertical space do as above.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I have Word 2010 so I don't know if this works on earlier versions. But what worked for me is to simply position the cursor on the bottom border of the row until you see two short horizontal lines with arrows above and below. Then simply move the bottom border up by holding down the mouse button and moving the mouse up. If the border won't stay up when you move it but springs back to its original position, you need to delete blank lines in the cells. Select the row and you will see selected blank space after the contents in some or all of the cells. To delete it, position the cursor at the end of the contents in the appropriate cell and press the delete key until only the contents remain selected. After doing this to all cells where blank space is selected, you should be able to move the border up with the mouse and it will stay. Clear as mud?

Answer (score 1):

Im using a Microsoft Word 2011 version for Mac.

I managed to solve this problem when I clicked on the "Table Layout" on the ribbon.

Click on 'Align' -> 'Center' or any one of those options that you prefer.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot where the settings are in 2003, but the settings you are looking for are the Cell margins, Cell alignment.

If they are a paragraph problem, just select one cell, and go under Format/Paragraph.  Zero out the After Line( or Paragraph, I forgot). Then just use format painter.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't help.  The cell alignment doesn't do anything with the spaces and only aligns the text to the field.  I don't see any configuration for "cell margin".  The before and after spacing is already at 0 pt, single line spacing.

Comment: Look under the Table menu/ table properties/ default Cell Margins. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/change-the-cell-margins-in-a-table-HP005257115.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If disabling "specify height" still doesn't work, try this:

(Based on Word 2003) Highlight the rows/columns of your interest and go to Format > Paragraph > Under the Spacing section, go to "Line Spacing" and choose either Single, 1.5, Double spacing or etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Word 2007. Highlight the table, click the home tab, then click the "maximize" button on the paragraph block  towards the middle of the page. You can access table paragraph spacing from here.